# SSL Certificate that use wildcards

Tags: ssl

At present I have two SSL certifcates for two URLS in the form:

url1.domain.com

url2.domain.com

I want to encrypt a third domain (url3.domain.com) and I'm thinking it might be best to move to just one certificate in the form:

*.domain.com

Are there any secuirty or techical considerations in moving away from two/three certificates to one wildcard certificate?

also...

Are there any issues with deploying a wildcard certificate (*.domain.com) for the new website whilst still using the other two specific certificates on the original websites?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Using a wildcard certificate can reduce your security a bit, as a compromise of the private key associated with the certificate on any one server will also compromise it on any other server using the same certificate.  It also makes it easier for an unscrupulous insider to run an unauthorized subdomain of the primary domain.  That said, many organizations find the convenience of administration of a single wildcard certificate outweighs these risks.

There are no technical issues with deploying the wildcard certificate on the new website, while using the specific certificates on the older web sites.  You're not getting much benefit from the wildcard certificate if you're only using for one address, though.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, Its best practice that using single Wildcard SSL Certificate for all sub domains. Ultimately , wildcard SSL certificate save time and money too.

I don’t think there are any issues for using wildcard SSL to secure multiple sub-domains as Google is also using Wildcard SSL for its sub-domains.

[image]